# Changed my Server ssh_config and now Putty displays black screen with green box: What do I do?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, bash, port

My hosting service sent me this [link](https://securitytrails.com/blog/mitigating-ssh-based-attacks-top-15-best-security-practices) to follow to prevent future brute force attacks on my VPS. I changed the port from 22 to 899, changed my deny file with

`sshd: ALL`

then added `sshd : 11.22.33.44` in my allow file changing the address with my own (both home and work on one line). I added AllowedUsers but deleted it after. I then ran the semanage command to allow the new port on my CentOs 7 OS and updated and restarted the ssh service ( in fact when I run a certan command (can't remember which, the 899 is shown as working.) I can get into my server through VNC from the host using root and password, but Putty just displays a black screen with green box. I did change Putty to use the new port, but my keys are the same.

I am pretty new to the server game but have been reading up heavily on it. I am just trying to prevent the 1000s of foreign login attempts so I can get to my forte of python programming. Any advice on how to fix this is super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the 899/tcp to firewalld/iptables?

> sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=899/tcp
>
> sudo firewall-cmd --reload

Also try without selinux enabled

> setenforce 0

Comment: yes, but i will try this again to make sure

Comment: nope to the setenforce

Comment: Don't change rules with `--permanent` and then reload the firewall. If you make a mistake, you could lock yourself out permanently. You should add the rule first, and then make it permanent only if it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer. I had switched my zones in firewall-cmd without adding the needed services!